# Color discrepancy between Emacs 22 and Emacs 23

Tags: emacs, emacs-faces

If .emacs contains the following two lines

```
(set-face-foreground 'modeline "#000000") 
(set-face-background 'modeline "#00FFFF")
```

then Emacs 22 correctly uses color #00FFFF (cyan), but Emacs 23
uses a different shade of blue (#90FBFE).

What is happening?

An image will illustrate the problem, but because I'm a new user here, stackoverflow will not let me save an image.
In the meantime, here is the image hosted elsewhere:
http://postimage.org/image/1j2ya1ddw/

Comment: Can you post the screenshots of the discrepancies that you observe?

Comment: I'm not sure if this would address your problem, but the approved way these days to set the mode line face these days is `M-x customize-face mode-line`.

Comment: Using customization produces identical results. "Red" is not red; "cyan" is not cyan; etc.

Comment: I see the discrepancies.  http://html-color-codes.com/ is the top hit I get for color hex codes on Google.  Are you referring to some standard color representations?  I am no expert in colors.  On my Emacs23 (on Debian Linux), "#00FFFF" and "#90FBFE" are different colors.  I don't have emacs22 handy though to see the differences for myself.  It could have something to do with standards of color representation.

Comment: Besides, `(color-values "cyan")` gives `(0 65535 65535)` in my emacs23 on Debian Linux.  That is, it thinks "#00FFFF" is cyan, and, "#90FBFE" is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 23 on OS X uses the new Cocoa front-end, and the colors are rendered incorrectly both in that version and in the current dev Emacs. I opened [a bug for this last week](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=8402), having been working on a color theme using precisely-selected colors, and the developers appear to be in the process of accepting the bug's validity.

Comment: This is it. Emacs 23 appears to be applying some function from the requested to the provided colors. The result is to somewhat wash-out the colors. We can put this issue to rest here, and if the interface at stackoverflow lets us, append a note later indicating the solution.

Comment: @user700648 Yep. Just mark this as the correct answer, and either of us can leave a comment later when the bug has been fixed.

Comment: If you want to fix it now I had some luck with a small change and a recompile of Emacs. See [this comment on the bug](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=8402#14).

Comment: @erik Thanks for confirming that the patch works. I'm hoping it will get committed to the official emacs tree.

Answer (score 0):

For me this two lines do their job, but if I set an alpha parameter of
a selected frame then colors change similar. I've looked at the
emacs 22.3 manual and found nothing about the alpha parameter. But if
you look at the [23.3 manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Font-and-Color-Parameters.html#Font-and-Color-Parameters) you could find this phrase in the `alpha'
parameter section:

> It can also have a `nil' value, which
>   tells Emacs not to set the frame
>   opacity (leaving it to the window
>   manager).

Maybe your window manager changes the colors of a frame? If it so this line of code can help you:

```
 (set-frame-parameter (selected-frame) 'alpha 100)
```

Comment: Nice suggestion, but that doesn't solve the problem. See http://postimage.org/image/2hnpry8v8 for the colors after setting alpha to 100.

Comment: @user700648 In the screenshot that is appended there is "#FFOOFFFF" value maybe you want to use "#00FFFF". I've seen the usage of values similar to "#FF00FFFFFF" [here] (http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TransparentEmacs), but they are not used in the 23 emacs. In the 22 emacs manual there is no such parameter as alpha parameter for a frame, so you don't need to specify it in the 22 emacs.

Comment: "#FFOOFFFF" was one of the variations I tried. The colors are also wrong when using "#OOFFFF".